# Animating battlefield data map of war in Ukraine

Tags: graphics, export, image-processing, geographics, video

### UPDATE on FINAL RESULT

Thanks to @SquareOne effort I generated higher-resolution videos with smoothing transitions that can be seen here:

- https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6926902980323512320/
- https://twitter.com/superflow/status/1521191832012705792

I might post my version of @SquareOne code with some bug corrections later. I am grateful to this community and @SquareOne for outstanding support.

### INTRO & *BOUNTY* TARGET

Dear friends, as you know there is currently an ongoing war in Ukraine: **https://war.ukraine.ua**

> ***I need your help on some coding in image/video processing, which is very simple to formulate, but not obvious in execution. Smooth exactly-timed transitions between video frames and perfect alignment of video frames is a key challenge here. BOUNTY TARGET IS EXPLAINED AT THE END OF THE POST.***

### DATA Description

*United States' [Institute for the Study of War](https://www.understandingwar.org/) (ISW, "a non-partisan, non-profit, public policy research organization") performs daily research and publishes daily maps of the battlefield. Their work is public and gives many references to data sources they use.  For instance...*

> **The whole-Ukraine overview map from the 1st day of invasion on FEB 24, 2022 ([source](https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/ukraine-conflict-update-7)):**

[image]

> **A recent whole-Ukraine overview map from APR 19, 2022 ([source](https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-april-19)):**

[image]

### DATA Source

These maps are published almost daily with all publications gathered here: https://www.understandingwar.org/publications

### *BOUNTY* TARGET

***BOUNTY WILL BE AWARDED TO the CODE GENERATING BEST .MP4 VIDEO of a SEQUENCE of MAPS.***

Basic part for the **BOUNTY**:

- **Programatic data access**. While URLs of daily articles and images follow some pattern, it is not always regular. *How do we write a piece of code that accesses whole-map programmatically?* We do not want do do this manually. Approach 1: look at the daily image URLs ([example](https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril19%2C2022.png)), but they are still not regular. Approach 2: look at the daily articles URLs and get 1st image from the article ([example](https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-april-19)), but they are still not regular. Maybe there are other approaches. **START DAT: FEB 24. END DATE: CURRENT DAY**.
- **Each frame must have a date stamp.** For example: FEB 24, 2022, FEB 25, 2022, etc.
- **Image alignment of Ukraine border - the GREATEST challenge**. All these maps-images are slightly different. Ukraine country border should NOT jump from frame to frame.
- **Duration of a frame and smoothness of transition** Each map-image (key-frame) should be held on screen 1 second. Each of 3 transitional blended frames should last 0.15 seconds. This is a toy example of how to achieve it. Imagine you have just 3 key-frames.

[image]

Build transitions via interpolated blended frames:

```
frames=Values[TimeSeriesResample[TimeSeries[imglist,{0}],1/4]]
```

[image]

Define non-inform timings as

```
In[68]:= timings=Flatten[Riffle[Table[1,3],{Table[.15,3]}]]
```

> Out[68]= {1,0.15`,0.15`,0.15`,1,0.15`,0.15`,0.15`,1}

Create video as

```
SlideShowVideo[frames -> timings]
```

[image]

Export to .MP4 via

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MP4.html

**Thank you very much for considering this!!!** Collecting data from independent sources, and displaying it in a comprehensive animation, can help to inform society in ways that numbers and unorganized static images cannot. This is the sort of thing we as a community can do best in these difficult times.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  this forum must be non-politital and non-ideological.

Comment: @user64494 your comment is off-topic in my opinion. I read the question carefully. Oh and yes. War is war. It's not politics and it's not ideology.

Comment: @user64494 I do not see ideology in using publicly available information that can be criticized and scrutinized. It shows a very relevant and useful application of WMA. You vote to close and I will vote to reopen. Simple as that. ;-)

Comment: Given the subject matter is of a political nature that has significant polarization, I vote to close this question. This is not an appropriate content for this forum.

Comment: I am asking for real coding help guys, real programing. These are NEUTRAL DATA from "a non-partisan, non-profit, public policy research organization". We do COVID data things right, while it is too can be political? But we help public to get factual knowledge. Sometimes code it might concern data about politics -- but this is no reason to block the pure data and code part of it. Even [Reddit DataIsBeautiful](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful) allows such entries -- and that is 17 million people sub-reddit with a lot of respect. Thanks :-)

Comment: @e.doroskevic This content is as real and relevant to the public as was COVID-19 information. It touches human lives and the study of war can be and has been done in a scientific way.

Comment: Absolutely @gwr -- I could not have expressed it better -- thank you !

Comment: to the author of the OP. taking into consideration the facts that 1. the question is related to data manipulation and software capabilities 2. politics was mentioned in the first negative comment not in the OP, and 3. there's only a handful of people supporting the war... the words "Russian war invasion hit a nerve it seems.

Comment: The only suspicious aspect of this question is the implication that @VitaliyKaurov has not already produced his own high-quality result...

Comment: Looking at the comments above, this is precisley the reason why this is not appropriate for this forum. There is certainly an element of programming here. This is not the reason why one promotes to close this question. I would suggest generalizing the matter to avoid politicalization.

Comment: It is always a pleasure to see how democracy does its works in this forum. Keep it up!

Comment: @gwr Of course, System Dynamics can be applied to model wars. I have been thinking to utilize your `SystemModeler` package ["Business Simulation"](https://github.com/bslMS/BusinessSimulation). So far I just did some modeling in WL -- it looks like the framework I made for COVID-19 simulations can be applied without change to war simulations. (See the project ["War-games-dynamics"](https://github.com/antononcube/SystemModeling/tree/master/Projects/War-games-dynamics).)

Comment: @e.doroskevic I agree with your point -- this question can easily bring fairly polarized groups at MSE. Basically, the question is: Can answers to this or similar questions be really subjective, without "editorial content."

Comment: @AntonAntonov Coyle immediately comes to my mind. His [System Dynamics Modeling—A Practical Approach](https://books.google.de/books?id=1MzxbV_ji_IC&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) has some examples on modeling warfare.

Comment: Taking various comments into account I edited and clarified the pure technical nature of this post. Thank you guys for all your feedback :-) Great community!

Comment: Addressing the question raised by @AntonAntonov, good answers here could have applicability for animating any data that changes over time and is cartography-based. Natural disaster zones come to mind, in terms of helping to determine what resources to focus where at what time. Another application might be charting deglaciation over decades. Sure, these both involve politics and policy. But the idea is to provide the best technical resources to aid in decision-making. This is important independent of the question at hand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eaVxxExRI-b14jKKJmaqEQIqZVZuv9JM/view?usp=sharing) is a link to a mp4 video (400 pixel width without fade transition due to memory limit in the the free basic Wolfram Cloud)

**1. Fetching**

The idea is to search all the ukraine-project pages for the links to all the reports containing the maps images. The name of the reports and of the images are searched given some keywords-string patterns.

All the images are downloaded locally (these are big images which need resizing).

```
webpage="https://www.understandingwar.org/project/ukraine-project";
pagePattern="?page=";
titlePattern="russian-offensive-campaign";
imageTitlePattern="UkraineCo"~~__~~".png";
maxpages= Import[webpage,"Hyperlinks"] // Select[StringContainsQ[pagePattern]] //StringCases[pagePattern~~d:DigitCharacter..->d] // Flatten//ToExpression // Max;

allReportsLinks=
Range[0,maxpages] // 
Map[(
Import[webpage<>pagePattern<>ToString@#, "Hyperlinks"]//
Select[StringContainsQ[titlePattern]]
)&
]//Flatten//Union;

allImagesLinks=allReportsLinks//
Map[{#,
Import[#,"Hyperlinks"]//Select[ StringContainsQ[imageTitlePattern]]//Union}&];

URLDownload[Select[allImagesLinks,Length@#[[2]]>0&]//#[[All,2,1]]&,"."];
```

**2. Resizing**

Once downloaded locally, the original maps are resized for convenience and are also directly renamed with the corresponding map date.

```
fn=FileNames["*Ukr*.png"];
imageWidth=300;
months2num={"April"->"04","March"->"03","Feb"->"02"};
filedatePatterns={(d:DigitCharacter..)~~m:("April"|"March"|"Feb"),
(LetterCharacter~~(m:"April"|"March"|"Feb")~~d:DigitCharacter..)};

allimagefiles=
Table[fn//Map[{#,StringCases[#,pattern:>
StringJoin[m/.months2num,If[StringLength@d==1,"0"<>d,d],"_",ToString@imageWidth,".png"]]}&],
{pattern,filedatePatterns}]// Map[Select[Length@#[[2]]==1&]]//Join@@#&//Map[Flatten];

Table[img=Import[imf[[1]]];
If[Head[img]===Image,Export[imf[[2]],ImageResize[img,imageWidth]]],{imf,allimagefiles}];
```

**3. Aligning**

The maps are aligned according to a caracteristic pattern which is always visible on all maps.

[image]

This image pattern is a small portion of the black sea on the east side with also two country borders:

[image]

The best results are obtained when extracting and comparing the edges of the images:

```
imgpatt=Import["0225_300.png"]//RemoveAlphaChannel//
ImageTake[#,{280,360},{250,295}]& //EdgeDetect[#,1]&
```

[image]

`ImageCorrelate` is used here to find the positions where the image pattern best matches the maps. It is then be possible to center all the maps onto this position-pattern.

```
bestpos[img_,pattern_]:= ImageCorrelate[img, pattern, 
NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance, Padding -> None] //
ColorConvert[#,"Graylevel"]& // ImageData // Position[#, Min[#]]&//
{#[[1,2]],ImageDimensions[img][[2]]-#[[1,1]] -ImageDimensions[pattern][[2]]}&


imageWidth=300;
finalfiles=FileNames["*_"<>ToString[imageWidth]<>".png"];
res=Table[img=Import[file]//RemoveAlphaChannel;xy=bestpos[EdgeDetect[img,1],imgpatt];{xy,ImageDimensions@img-xy},{file,finalfiles}];
{xg,yb,xd,yh}=Transpose@res//Map[Transpose]//Flatten[#,1]&//Map[Max];
i0=Image[Graphics[{White,Rectangle[{0,0},{xg+xd,yb+yh}]}],ImageSize->{xg+xd,yb+yh}];

imgs=Table[img=Import[file]//RemoveAlphaChannel;
ImageCompose[i0,img,{xg,yb},bestpos[EdgeDetect[img,1],imgpatt]],{file,finalfiles}];
```

**4. Movie**

Assembling the images into a movie as indicated by @Vitaly:

```
frames=Values[TimeSeriesResample[TimeSeries[imgs,{0}],1/3]];
timings=Flatten[Riffle[Table[0.30,Length@finalfiles],{Table[.15,2]}]];
Remove[imgs];
SlideShowVideo[frames -> timings]
```

**---------------------------Previous**

Just a proof of concept with 4 maps, i have not finished yet. I tried to align the full images with different approaches, `ImageCorrelate` seems to give here the more robust results.

[image]

Comment: +1 Excellent start, thank you! I am looking forward to see the code - surprising `ImageCorrelate` works with such randomly-detailed images. Can't wait to see the .mp4 :-)

Comment: This does look quite good. But it needs the code in order to count as a proper MSE response.

Comment: @SquareOne it is just 1 hour left :-) Actually it maybe a bit more - I think there is a small grace period after bounty ends.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I am working on it ... I hope I will make it

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov By the way, any idea how to publish the video ? Imgur ??

Comment: @SquareOne That would work. But also I guess any file sharing service - from dropbox-like to YouTube-like (if you got account you can showcase your work) to anonymous things like file.io or imgur.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Ok, I have a very weird bug somewhere, I will be back in a few hours ... (it is the night here) ;)

Comment: @SquareOne this is wonderful ! Do you have an .mp4 video link? Let me know if you need any help. This all work is very important. Please let's finish it.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Link added beneath the gif. I am glad you like it and that it can help ! (I was limited concerning the size of the video and the transition effect (too many frames) because of the memory limit in the free basic plan.). Of course, there are many ways to improve this work. In particular concerning the image processing (i am not at all a pro in this domain), the matching is not so robust, I have already some ideas I hope I can test soon.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Interesting, I thought it is just 67 (days) * 4 (transition) = 268 frames - pretty small for a video. Also I see you got just 19 seconds video - also pretty small. "the memory limit in the free basic plan" - are you using Cloud not desktop?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov  I am using the free basic Wolfram cloud, the kernel crash if I try to add transitions between the images as soon as I work with 400 pixels width images. Impossible also to create a video at 500 pixels width even without transitions. It would nice to have an out-of-core function for this ...
The total number of images I have is 53. Some reports do not include at all maps (e.g. 26th of Feb), I also had a broken link ... I might also have missed some of the images due to file spelling ... I did not check yet all the reasons, these are indeed part of the work to improve.

Comment: I just sent you an email to the address mentioned in your profile, so we do not abuse comment space too much :-)

Answer (score 17):

Here's a first pass at naively grabbing and animating the main map frames:

```
april = Table[
dayImgs = Import["https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-april-"<>ToString[n],"Images"];
img = dayImgs[[5]]; (* brittle *)
ymax=Max@ImageValuePositions[Image@ImageData[img][[All,{10,10}]],{0.9686274509803922`,0.9686274509803922`,0.9686274509803922`,1.`}][[All,2]];
ymin=Max@ImageValuePositions[Image@ImageData[img][[All,{10,10}]],{0.,0.,0.,1.}][[All,2]];
ImageTrim[img,{{2550,ymax},{0,ymin}}],
{n,1,19}]

ListAnimate[april]
```

[image]

Or you can try:

```
SlideShowVideo[Thread[april->1]]
```

**Update:**

Another approach could be to try registering with `GeoGraphics` and using color analysis to get "the locations", here's a sketch:

```
dayImgs = Import["https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-april-18","Images"];
img = dayImgs[[5]]; (* same as above *)
ymax=Max@ImageValuePositions[Image@ImageData[img][[All,{10,10}]],{0.9686274509803922`,0.9686274509803922`,0.9686274509803922`,1.`}][[All,2]];
ymin=Max@ImageValuePositions[Image@ImageData[img][[All,{10,10}]],{0.,0.,0.,1.}][[All,2]];
i=ImageTrim[img,{{2550,ymax},{0,ymin}}]

(* Extract the legend colors and overlay graphics *)
{rc,uc}={RGBColor[0.9568629185428273, 0.6901959859893049, 0.6862744789494377, 1.], 
 RGBColor[0.6666667137194934, 0.9137255348660686, 0.9882353221073724, 1.]};
{ru,ua}=Image[ColorReplace[Image[DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[Blur[ColorDetect[i, ColorsNear[#, 0]], 6], .1]]],
{White->#, Black->Transparent}],ImageSize->{613.7,650.6}]&/@{rc,uc};

g=GeoGraphics["World", 
GeoRange->{{38.5, 53.89}, {24.69, 39.5}},ImageSize->{613.7,650.6}, (* guesstimates *)
GeoProjection->"Mercator", GeoBackground->"CountryBorders"];
Magnify[Row[{Overlay[{g,ru,ua}],i}],.5]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you! Quite elegant in its compactness. If I understand correctly you are alleging images simply by their sides, using the fact that it looks like Ukrainian border is always in the same position within the map? BTW there are a few reasons to keep the top and bottom parts of the frame - like it has the date, other info, etc. But this is a great start!

Comment: The size of the blue top and the bottom footnote sections sometimes change in height, to keep the image aligned I removed them. Instead, you could use `TextRecognize` on the header and footer and add labels or annotations. If you have any next step ideas here, please chat me and I'd be happy to try and add them.

Comment: I updated technical details (see the end of the post) and posted 500 bounty. Thanks  for the consideration and help.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov it's straightforward to do what you're asking now with these snippets, I'll try to finish your 500pt request tonight

Comment: I am looking forward to it, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

> With my limited knowledge I could do **Programmatic data access**. I hope it would be useful for other answers.

> The code provided in this answer is introduced to show the procedure and the author does not hold any responsibility for its usage.

Although some days don't have images (like [February 20](https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russia-ukraine-warning-update-russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-february-26)) and there isn't a consistency in naming, below code almost find all the images to this date (except for [March 20](https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-march-20) which is named really differently).

The code below defines a function named `scrapImageURLs` which returns a list of image URLs based on your second approach (opening the URL and looking for the image). Then use `URLDownload` to download them on your computer and process them.

You can use `"StartDate"` and `"EndDate"` options to filter your requests.

```
ClearAll[scrapImageURLs];

Options[scrapImageURLs]:={"StartDate"->{2022,2,25},"EndDate":>Floor[AbsoluteTime[]-86400,86400]};

scrapImageURLs[OptionsPattern[]]:=Block[{startDate=Max[Floor[AbsoluteTime@OptionValue["StartDate"],86400],AbsoluteTime@{2022,2,25}],endDate=Min[Ceiling[AbsoluteTime@OptionValue["EndDate"],86400],Ceiling[AbsoluteTime[],86400]],imageURLs,imageURL={},getError=False},

imageURLs=Table[Block[{dayString=ToLowerCase@DateString[day,{"MonthName","-","DayShort"}],justDayString=ToString@DateValue[day,"DayShort"],url,response},

url=Which[day===AbsoluteTime[{2022,2,25}],
"https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russia-ukraine-warning-update-russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-february-25-2022",

day===AbsoluteTime[{2022,2,28}],
"https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-february-28-2022",

day<AbsoluteTime[{2022,2,28}],
"https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russia-ukraine-warning-update-russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-"<>dayString,


True,"https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-"<>dayString];

response=URLRead[url];

If[response["StatusCode"]===200,
imageURL=StringCases[response["Body"],"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/draft"~~Shortest[___]~~((justDayString~~Shortest[___]~~"ukraine")|("ukraine"~~Shortest[___]~~justDayString))~~Shortest[___]~~".png",IgnoreCase->True],Print["   ERROR on "<>dayString<>"\n   "<>url<>"\n   \"StatusCode\": "<>ToString[response["StatusCode"]]];getError=True;];

If[Not@getError,
If[Length@imageURL=!=0,Print[First@imageURL];First@imageURL,Print["   No image found on "<>dayString<>"\n   ",url];Nothing],Nothing]

]
,{day,Range[startDate,endDate,86400]}];

imageURLs

]
```

Notes:

- It uses `URLRead` which was introduced in version 11.
- Since it could fail at any moment during execution, it'll print the result/error it faced while executing and return a list of valid image URLs (for days that have an image and don't get an error).
- It assumes the image filename starts with `"draft"` and ends with `".png"` and the day and the word `"ukraine"` is also included (for example March-19 has `19` in its name)
- **Please save the URLs and only request for days that you don't have.**

---

Just to avoid putting pressure on servers, here is the list of image URLs up to `2022-4-20`:

```
{"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTFeb25%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTFeb27%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTFeb28%2C2022_0.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch1%2C2022_0.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch2%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch3%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch4%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch5%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch6%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch7%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch8%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch9%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch10%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch11%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch12%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch13%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoT_14March2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCotMarch15%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch16%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch17%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch18%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch19%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/UkraineCoTMarch20%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch21%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch22%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch23%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch24%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch25%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch26%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch27%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch28%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch29%2C2022_0.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch30%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTMarch31%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril1%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril2%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril3%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril4%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril5%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril6%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril7%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril8%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril9%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril10%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril11%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril12%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCotApril13%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril14%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril15%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril16%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril17%2C2022.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril18%2C2022_0.png",
"https://www.understandingwar.org/sites/default/files/DraftUkraineCoTApril19%2C2022.png"}
```

Comment: +1 Thank very much - this is very useful! I hope it is robust against possible typos in their URLs, so we do not miss a date.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. Its robustness could always fail facing unpredictable names, but overall it'll find most of the links and when it doesn't, the post URL along with a "no image found/error" text will be printed to get it manually. I hope the list doesn't get much bigger.